# How can I number my points and subpoints which has an unlimited number of nested objects using recursive function and js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, recursion, recursive-datastructures

let's say I have data something like this

```
    let data = [
    {
        subPoint:[
            {
                point:'point a 1.1',
            },
            {
                point:'point a 1.2',
            },
            {
                subPoint:[
                    {
                        subPoint:[
                            {
                                point:'point a 1.3.1.1'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        point:'point a 1.3.1.2'
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        point:'point b 1'
    },
    {
        point:'point c 1'
    },
    {
        subPoint:[
            {
                subPoint:[
                    {
                        point:'point d 1.1.1'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My intended result should be something like this

```
[
  '1.1.1---point a 1.1',
  '1.1.2---point a 1.2',
  '1.1.3.1.1---point a 1.3.1.1',
  '1.1.3.1.2---point a 1.3.1.2',
  '2.1---point b 1',
  '3.1---point c 1',
  '4.1.1.1---point d 1.1.1'
]
```

But what I am getting is this

```
[
  '1.3.1---point a 1.1',
  '1.3.2---point a 1.2',
  '1.3.3.1.1.1---point a 1.3.1.1',
  '1.3.3.1.2---point a 1.3.1.2',
  '2---point b 1',
  '3---point c 1',
  '4.1.1.1---point d 1.1.1'
]
```

my code looks like this

```
const getInfo = (starIndex,array) => {
    let rowId = starIndex
    array.forEach((val,ind) => {
        if(val.subPoint){
            console.log(starIndex)
            rowId = starIndex+'.'+(ind+1)

            return getInfo(rowId,val.subPoint)
        }
    })
    console.log('rowId',rowId)
    return rowId
}
let returnData = []
const getData = (_data,val) => {

    _data.forEach((_dat,index) => {
        let value = (val?`${val}.`:'')+`${index+1}`
        if(_dat.subPoint){
            value = getInfo(value,_dat.subPoint)
            getData(_dat.subPoint,value)
        }else {
            returnData.push(value+ '---' + _dat.point)
        }
    })
    return returnData
}

console.log(getData(data))
```

I think I missing something or my recursion is bad I am not sure what the issue is,

This is a metaphorical code for a problem I have the actual problem has to do deal with giving a unique id for each table row component which can have any number of grouping.

Comment: why `1.1.3.1.1.1` instead of `1.3.1.1`? where do get the extra `1` from?

Comment: @NinaScholz yea just noticed, that's an issue as well. Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

Without extra levels.

```js
const
    getFlat = (parent = '') => ({ point, subPoint = [] }, i) => {
        const
            p = parent + (parent && '.') + (i + 1),
            children = subPoint.flatMap(getFlat(p));

        if (point) children.unshift([p, point].join('---'));

        return children;
    },
    data = [{ subPoint: [{ point: 'point a 1.1' }, { point: 'point a 1.2' }, { subPoint: [{ subPoint: [{ point: 'point a 1.3.1.1' }] }, { point: 'point a 1.3.1.2' }] }] }, { point: 'point b 1' }, { point: 'point c 1' }, { subPoint: [{ subPoint: [{ point: 'point d 1.1.1' }] }] }],
    result = data.flatMap(getFlat());

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: why was the line ``if (point) children.unshift([p, point].join('---'))`` used , wouldn't push do the trick?

Comment: @anoopfrancis, this line move the actual (given point) to the right position of the result set, before the following children nodes.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
  {
    subPoint: [
      {
        point: 'point a 1.1',
      },
      {
        point: 'point a 1.2',
      },
      {
        subPoint: [
          {
            subPoint: [
              {
                point: 'point a 1.3.1.1',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            point: 'point a 1.3.1.2',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    point: 'point b 1',
  },
  {
    point: 'point c 1',
  },
  {
    subPoint: [
      {
        subPoint: [
          {
            point: 'point d 1.1.1',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
const flatten = (data) => {
  let result = [];
  const recurse = (data, path = '') => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let item = data[i];
      let newPath = path ? `${path}.${i + 1}` : `${i + 1}`;
      if (item.point) {
        result.push(`${newPath}---${item.point}`);
      } else {
        recurse(item.subPoint, newPath);
      }
    }
  };
  recurse(data);
  return result;
}
console.log(flatten(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

This output does not match your request, but it seems much more logical to me:

```js
[
  "1.1---point a 1.1",
  "1.2---point a 1.2",
  "1.3.1.1---point a 1.3.1.1",
  "1.3.2---point a 1.3.1.2",
  "2---point b 1",
  "3---point c 1",
  "4.1.1---point d 1.1.1"
]
```

If that works for you, here is a simple recursion that will generate it:

```js
const outline = (xs, path = []) => xs .flatMap (({point, subPoint = []}, i) => point 
  ? [`${path .concat (i + 1) .join ('.')}---${point}`] 
  : outline (subPoint, path .concat (i + 1))
)

const data = [{subPoint: [{point: "point a 1.1"}, {point: "point a 1.2"}, {subPoint: [{subPoint: [{point: "point a 1.3.1.1"}]}, {point: "point a 1.3.1.2"}]}]}, {point: "point b 1"}, {point: "point c 1"}, {subPoint: [{subPoint: [{point: "point d 1.1.1"}]}]}]

console .log (outline (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We track a running path, that might contain values such as `[2]` or `[1, 3, 1, 1]`, and on each call, if we've hit a node with a `point` property we combine the path with that property string.  If we haven't we add the current index (plus one to deal with JS's zero-based counting) to the path, and recur on the children of the `subPoint` node.

If that output doesn't work, can you explain exactly where each of your target outline prefixes comes from?

Comment: yes this is exactly what I want